# How to store likes dislikes love and anger in Postgres table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

- I have the typical posts and comments structure
- Posts can have likes dislikes love and anger
- Comments can have likes and dislikes
- Initially came up with a very silly schema

This one has a user table, a post table and a post votes table where likes, dislikes, love and anger are stored in separate columns

```
User (userId, email, password..)
Post (postId, link, summary...)
PostVotes (postVoteId, likes, dislikes, love, anger)
UserVotes (userVoteId, userId references User.userId, postVoteId references PostVotes.postVoteId)

Comments (commentId, parentCommenId, comment, publishedDate, userId)
CommentVotes (commentVoteId, likes, dislikes, commentId references Comments.commentId)
UserCommentVotes (userCommentVoteId, commentVoteId references CommentVotes, userId references User.userId)
```

- Yea I agree, this is not the right way to do it
- Read a few posts here and there on stackoverflow and dba.stackexchange.com and got an idea

Instead of keeping 2 separate tables for post votes and comment votes, make a single one called Votes

```
Votes (itemId, userId, vote)
```

- How do I make itemId references commentId and postId
- If I use +1 for likes and -1 for dislikes, how do I represent love and anger?
- Can I make an enum of integers or something, will I be able to sum the likes dislikes love and anger if it is an enum or should I count it by keeping it as text enum
- Should I make a materialized view to get likes dislikes love and anger per post?

My query would be to load 50 posts on each load in an infinitely scrolling page. I would need to get likes dislikes love and anger for each one of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? Could you share it as an Answer or Comment here?